# Answer deleted by moderator

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I [answered](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75700/what-if-a-bullet-hit-wonder-woman/75708#75708) a question [What if a bullet hit Wonder Woman?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75700/what-if-a-bullet-hit-wonder-woman/75708#75708).  It got more votes that the accepted answer, but then a moderator decided to delete it and gave the reason "This does not answer the question, which is tagged dceu, and should be removed."

But as I explained in the comments

1. That dceu tag was added by another user, not the OP
2. The OP did not state that is was only CANON, or only the movie.
3. The tag description talks about a shared universe, which usually includes more than just canon.
   So in conclusion. I believe my post does answer the question.

Yes, I admit it was a funny answer, and not cannon to the universe, and I had even updated the answer to state that prior to it being deleted.

However I would like to appeal to get this answer un-deleted.  What does the community opinion on this?

P.S.  Why is there only a deleted-questions tag and not a deleted-answer tag and should we create one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Napoleon has explained perfectly why your answer was deleted, but since he's a mod and you're asking for the *community* opinion, I'd like to draw your attention to [this Meta question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2855/46980) discussing your answer back when it was posted, and whether such joke answers should be allowed.

The question itself has 11 upvotes and only one downvote. The accepted answer (which I will concede was also posted by Napoleon) says "No, it shouldn't", and has 10 upvotes and only one downvote. The only other answer agreed that it was rightfully deleted, but was downvoted to -3 merely for suggesting it was deleted too quickly. And then, of course, there's this question, where your suggestion of un-deleting the answer is currently at -4 and Napoleon's rebuttal is at +6.

The community consensus seems clear: the answer was rightfully deleted and should stay deleted.

---

FWIW, I remember when the answer was first posted, and while I did find it amusing, I agree that it should remain deleted. Not just because it's a joke answer, but because **it was a fan-made comic and not official in any way.** If we allowed fan material to be posted as answers here - serious or otherwise - then there's nothing stopping me from answering (say) "[Did Homer and Marge ever cheat on each other?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96009/did-the-simpsons-cartoon-couple-ever-cheat-on-each-other)" with "Yes, Marge cheats on Homer in this 3,000-word fanfic that I conveniently posted on AO3 ten minutes ago".

Comment: Heh! I totally forgot we already discussed this thing. Might even just close this meta question as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the DCEU tag was added to the question since that is what the question is asking about by the mere fact it was asked on this site and this isn't Comics.SE but Movies & TV. You simply *can't* ask a question about every or any possible Wonder Woman incarnation and not have it be related to a film. But even then, we could say answers from the comics source material might be relevant additional information, provided they don't downright contradict the film content and try to at least make a cursory connection to the film.

However, your answer did neither. **Not only did it not relate to the film at all, it didn't even relate to the *comics source material either*. You yourself say it's not canonical and just a joke.** It was a supposedly funny joke comment, *nothing else*. And frankly, the votes on it don't really mean squat, it's a joke "answer" on an HNQ question, *of course* people will upvote it, that doesn't really say much about its merits as an actual answer. (Other non-moderator users on the other hand voted to delete it and flagged it as "not an answer".)

To address your specific points:

1. Yes, users can improve other people's questions with helpful edits on these sites, and in order to even be on-topic the question was *either* about the DCEU *or* about the 70s TV-show. And at the time of asking the former was a sufficiently safe bet.
2. He did implicitly, by asking it on this site and thereby looking for a serious answer.
3. Yes, a shared universe might include a lot, and information from the source material can be relevant, too. It does, however, *not* include parody comics made by random internet people, unless proven otherwise.

And even if we forget all these points and concentrate on the answer itself, it doesn't even provide *any information*, it throws a funny picture at us without even elaborating what the conclusion therefrom is even if we were willing to accept the comic as a serious source.

So on the bottom line, **this answer had absolutely no right to exist** as an answer, and to say "but a lot of people found it funny" won't really change much about that.

Comment: To be honest, the thought it could be in any way a reasonable answer to the question asked seems odd enough to make me even wonder about the seriousness of this very appeal 1.5 years after its deletion. But I'm willing to take this meta question serious and answered it as such, even if that means declining the appeal for undeletion.